# Truffle promise: Why reassign instance in callback?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

In the Truffle documentation, for interaction with contracts, the returned contract `instance` is assigned to `meta` before being interacted with:

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // an address
var account_two = "0xabcd..."; // another address

var meta;
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;                               // <- Reasignment!
  return meta.sendCoin(account_two, 10, {from: account_one});
}).then(function(result) {
  // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
  alert("Transaction successful!")
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

Why do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that you can chain another function call using the same instance. For example to elaborate on their example:

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // an address
var account_two = "0xabcd..."; // another address

var meta;
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;                               // <- Reasignment!
  return meta.sendCoin(account_two, 10, {from: account_one});
}).then(function(result) {
  // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
  console.log("Transaction successful!");
  return meta.getBalance.call(account_two)
}).then(function(balance) {
  // can call more functions using the same instance of meta
  alert("Balance = " + balance);
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to assign it to a global variable in the context of the code you've shared. It's only useful if you want to use it outside the scope of the first callback (the first `.then()`) which is probably what they're trying to demonstrate.